# [NSPathStore2 finishedPlaying]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, selector, ios3.0

Intermittently while running my program it crashes out with:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPathStore2 finishedPlaying]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x286e20'`

According to the internet there is zero documentation available on this function so I turn to you illustrious Stack Overflow.

It somewhat seems to coincide with the loading/playing of sounds using the CocosDenshion library. I can't be sure exactly where (if it is) because it never seems to happen while I am stepping through.

This is while testing on a 1st Gen iPod Touch with 3.1.3 installed. The program works flawlessly on devices with iOS 3.2 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to bump this old topic, but I have been struggling with the same issue for a couple weeks and wanted to share my experience.

A small percentage of my users are getting fatal exceptions of the format: 
"[__NSCFNumber finishedPlaying:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fa8ed40"
It seems to be limited to iOS 6 devices, but it has been impossible to debug since I can't reproduce it myself.

I believe the two other answers are barking up the wrong tree.  Both suggest that the problem is related the AVAudioPlayer delegate, which is the problem discussed in [The reason behind crash in AVAudioPlayer finishedPlaying after upgrade to iPhone 3.0 OS](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Aug/msg00126.html). But you'll notice that in this case the finishedPlaying method is successfully called and the exception there is related to the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: method.

In this problem it is the finishedPlaying: selector that is not recognized, meaning that it is the AVAudioPlayer itself who is no longer valid, rather that its delegate.

Upon this realization I now think that the problem is a result of the AVAudioPlayer being incorrectly managed (I was using a non-ARC helper class: NTAVManager).  I've updated the class to use ARC and hope this will fix my problem, but as I said I have never been able to reproduce it myself so I won't be able to confirm for a few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is:

```
AVAudioPlayer_Instance.delegate = nil;
```

`AVAudioPlayer_Instance` is your instance of `AVAudioPlayer` and this should be called before `dealloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [The reason behind crash in AVAudioPlayer finishedPlaying after upgrade to iPhone 3.0 OS](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Aug/msg00126.html)

I suspect that the reference to the AVAudioPlayer delegate is no longer valid, and the message is being sent to the address of a different object (NSPathStore2 in your case).